# Python read() seems to return less data than it reads

Tags: python, file-io

Can anyone tell me why the length of data is much less than the position of the end of the file? I would have expected these to be equal.

```
>>> target = open('target.jpg')
>>> print target.tell()
0
>>> data = target.read()
>>> print target.tell()
40962
>>> print len(data)
52
```

Comment: btw-You shouldn't need to "print" as your example shows.  When working from the python console, it will output the results for you.

Comment: Cheers @monkut. I didn't consider that because I pasted from a script I was writing into the console. Also, I often use `print` when I expect the value may be `None`, because then it can actually be seen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode:

```
target = open('target.jpg','rb')
```

I would not trust tell() on a file not opened as binary.

---

Later: actually, on reviewing the comments, I should have said I would not trust a `read` on a binary file opened as text.

Comment: Ah ha! I love it when the solution is simple. I'll accept as soon as I'm allowed.

Comment: really what's happening is that when you're not reading the file as binary, the read() command stops at the first character that is interpretted as an EOF character.

Comment: @Justin Peel: What's really happening is that it stops on the first Ctrl-Z (\x1A) **byte** if and only if you are running on Windows.

Comment: @John, oh, okay, I always thought it was some sort of EOF, but that makes more sense.

Comment: @Justin Peel: It *is* "some sort of EOF", inherited from CP/M via MS-DOS. CP/M recorded file sizes in 128-byte sectors, hence the need for some in-band EOF signal for text files.

Comment: Once again I hit a Windows-specific case. I should really stop using it to code projects that are deployed on a linux server.